VS Code incorrectly shows typescript error 'Cannot find name' when using project from parent folder with '.' in folder name
My company has a mono repo called cloud-platform and our React app inside a folder called web-app.
I'm getting the error Cannot find name 'jest'. ts(2304) from a folder inside cloud-platform/web-app/.jest/setupJest.ts
I only get this error when using VS Code from the cloud-platform level, and if the folder has a . in the beginning of the name (if I rename the folder to utils or anything else it works).
If I open VS Code from just the web-app directory the .jest folder structure works fine.
Anyone able to help sort out why this would happen? I can't find any settings or anything


I had to include the new setup file under my test-specific tsconfig:
// tsconfig.spec.json

{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../../../../dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["jest", "node"],
    "strict": false
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.tsx",
    "**/*.spec.js",
    "**/*.spec.jsx",
    "**/*.d.ts",
    "jest.config.ts",
    "jest.setup.ts" <-- My added setup file
  ]
}

